# Cross relating PhP / Mysql field in SELECT command from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, fetch

I currently have two tables, one is Members (storing userid numbers, usernames, passwords) and one is Wire (which stores user submitted data: category, contents, date, the user number who contributed - automatically fetched from a current session variable called $_SESSION['user_id'].)

Once submitted, just for examples sake, a line from the Wire table might look like:

**category** |   **contents**   |   **date**   | **userid**

Beef     |   it's good  | 10/08/213 |  5

So user number 5 selected beef and wrote "it's good" on October 5th. In the separate Members table, user 5's username is let's say John.

I then have a get.php that pulls up this info and puts it into a table for all to see.
I'm rather new, so this might be easy, but my question is in my get.php, how do I get it to replace "5" and put in "John?"  I looked up join commands but I'm not sure how to relate it to my code.   Here's the section of my get.php that creates the table:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM wire order by date DESC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Contents</th>
<th>Date/Time</th>
<th>Username</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contents'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";  //change 5 to John
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

If it helps, the logins are all managed by the system in this tutorial: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to join the two table together so you can get the Name in the same result.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT opwire.*,members.username FROM opwire 
          JOIN members ON opwire.userid=members.id order by date DESC");
```

Then you can `echo` the name by changing the userid to the name

```
echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";  // change this
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";  // to this
```

Comment: That seems to be breaking the table, is my Echo incorrect perhaps?  I just have echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";

Comment: Yea you need to change `Members.name` to be the members table name and the columns of the username so it could be something like `users.username`..Also the array in the result you get is associated with the columns you get back. So if you want the name you need to specify the column name `$row['usernamecolumn']`

Comment: If you post the schema for the table that contains names, we can help get you the right names

Comment: Ok,  here are the actual names |  Table opwire: (category, contents, date, userid)   then...  Table members: (id, username, email, password, salt)

Comment: That worked!  Sort of!  It puts in the right information now, just for some reason it kicked out all the testing data I had with no username attached.  Odd.  Still,  great step forward!  Thank you guys for the help with this, I think I'm following the logic of how it's working.

Comment: @sylcat, If you had data in the opwire table that does not correspond with a row in the members table, then you can do a `LEFT JOIN` to get all the data see here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Rock on! That fixed it up. There are so many subtleties I have to learn yet.  Thanks so much again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (don't have time to try it):

```
 "SELECT category, contents, date, username 
FROM wire join members on wire.userid=memebers.userid" order by date DESC"
```

This should give you an array like the one you have but instead of $row['userid'] you will use $row['username'];